# how to use GitHub environment variable in Actions?

Tags: node.js, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I added environment variables (`NODE_ENV`) in my '`dev`' GitHub **Environment**.
How can I use it in my Action for my self-hosted runner on AWS?

[image: GitHub]

Now, I tried in this way:

```yaml
- name: start pm2 service
      env:
        NODE_ENV: ${{ secrets.NODE_ENV }}
      run: NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV pm2 start ./bin/www --name 'backend'
```

But I can't get the env on the AWS, my app shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try and and use the [official example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow)

```yaml
steps:
  - shell: bash
    env:
      NODE_ENV: ${{ secrets.NODE_ENV }}
    run: |
      echo "NODE=ENV='$NODE_ENV'"
      pm2 start ./bin/www --name 'backend'
```

Since `NODE_ENV` is exported, you might not need to prefix `pm2` with `NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV`.

However, since the value is still empty, that would confirm the "[External Configuration/Secret Sources](https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/6)" is not fully supported yet for an AWS App Runner, assuming it is used for a Github self-hosted runner execution.
That differs from the fact [App Runners support GitHub Actions since Nov. 2021](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-app-runner-github-actions-build-deploy-applications/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. but I still got undefined when I try to get the NODE_ENV by using `process.env.NODE_ENV;`

Comment: @ChenhuaFan I have edited the answer to illustrate why this might not work.